# How to fail codebuild if testing coverage is below a threshold?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am new to AWS codeBuild and code pipeline, what I am wondering is if there is a way I can fail a pipeline or codeBuild project if the coverage of my test cases is below a certain threshold, i.e 80%?

I have an angular project configured with Karma & Jasmine.
Upon research I have found that I can use this command `aws codebuild stop-build --id ${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID}`, not sure if this will help me in any way?

**Buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:

      # Install the Angular CLI
      - npm install -g @angular/cli

      # Install puppeteer as a dev dependency
      - npm i -D puppeteer
      - npm i -D @angular-devkit/build-angular

      # Print out missing libs
      - echo "Missing Libs" || ldd ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome | grep not

      # Upgrade apt
      - apt-get upgrade

      # Update libs
      - apt-get update

      # Install apt-transport-https
      - apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

      # Use apt to install the Chrome dependencies
      - apt-get install -y libxcursor1
      - apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev
      - apt-get install -y libxss1
      - apt-get install -y libasound2
      - apt-get install -y libnspr4
      - apt-get install -y libnss3
      - apt-get install -y libx11-xcb1

      # Print out missing libs
      - echo "Missing Libs" || ldd ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome | grep not

      # Install project dependencies
      - npm install
      
      # - usermod -g 0 -o codebuild-user

  build:
    # run-as: codebuild-user
    commands:
      # Run headless Chrome tests
      - ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox --watch=false --code-coverage
      - printenv
```

I wish to condition the ng tests output here to fail the pipeline.

```
      - aws codebuild stop-build --id ${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID}

artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Comment: I would just return an error code instead of calling `aws codebuild stop-build` from within the build itself.

Comment: Alright how do I do that? `Exit 1`?Also, how will I fail it at a certain percentage of coverage?

Comment: Yes `exit 1`. I guess you would have to parse the output from `ng test` to get the coverage.

Comment: did you try configuring `coverage-istanbul` plugin to set thresholds on code coverage for build failures... this configuration by default fails your ng test if the thresholds are not met making codebuild fail instead of manually doing `exit 1`

Comment: I was hoping to know about solutions that help me fail the codebuild but yes, I am aware of istanbul.